# I am getting an error in my Vue page but my project is running despite the error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex-modules

[image: warning picture]

[Vue warn]: provide is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning, it's not an error.
In some cases, you can ignore it and leave your life peacefully.

If you want to have more help regarding the warning, I guess that you need to find out where this part of the code is called.

Comment: I FİX THİS ; I added it to main.js
Vue.config.silent = true

Comment: @YasinElmas this is not really a solution, more of a "I hide the problem".